# Arch Linux installation not starting

Tags: arch-linux, boot

I am trying to install arch for the first time,was a mint user and I cant even get to the installation screen or terminal.Here is all I get[image] and then the machine reboots.

Comment: Is SecureBoot enabled? Select `Reboot Into Firmware Interface`, then find and disable SecureBoot, OR from Windows (if you have it installed), search for and use the `Reboot from USB` function. If neither work, check the USB drive for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to add the `nomodeset` flag to the kernel parameter while booting.